# Integral Using Dominated Convergence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, integration

Prove that for $a>-1$ we have $\int_{[0,1]}x^{a}(1-x)^{-1}\log(x)\, dx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(a+n)^{2}}$.

--It is shown previously that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_{n}(x)$ converges a.e. to an integrable function and $\int\sum_{n}f_{n}=\sum_{n}\int f_{n}$. I am trying to use DCT for this integral, but am having trouble finding a dominating function $g(x)$. Also, where does the $n$ terms come from in the solution? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Expand $(1-x)^{-1}$ into a geometric series.